# How many lines are too many when reading from a file?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I intend to make a dynamic list in php, for which I have a plain text file with an element of the list in every line. Every line has a string that needs to be parsed into several smaller chunks before rendering the final html document.

Last time I did something similar, I used a file() function to load my file into an array, but in this case I have a 12KB file with more than 50 lines, that will most certainly grow bigger over time. Should I load the entries from the file to a SQL database to avoid performance issues?

Comment: Depends... how long is a piece of string (or, line, in this case)?

Comment: It varies between 100 and 400 characters

Comment: 12kB by itself is nothing; even `file()` would be fast, not sure how much you do per item though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, put the information into a data base.  Not for performance reasons (in terms of sequential reading) because a 12KB file will be read very quickly, but for the part about parsing into separate chunks.  Make those chunks into columns of your DB table.  It will make the whole programming process go faster, with greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking stuff up in to properly formatted database is -almost- always a good idea and will be a performance saver.

However, 50 lines is pretty minor (even a few hundred lines is pretty minor). A bit of quick math, 12KB / 50 lines tells me each line is only about 240 characters long on average.

I doubt that amount of processing (or even several times that much) will be a significant enough performance hit to cause dread unless this is a super high performance site.

Answer (score 0):

While 50 lines doesn't seem like too much, it would be a good idea to use the database now rather than making the change later. One think you would have to remember is that using database won't straight-away eliminate performance issues, but help you make better use of resources. In fact, you can write a similarly optimized process using files too, and they would work just about the same except for I/O difference.

I reread the question and you realize that you might mean that you would load the file to the database every time. I don't see how this can help unless you are using database as a form of cache to avoid repeated hits to the file. Ultimately, reading from a file or database would only differ in how the script uses I/O, disk caches, etc... The processing you do on the list might make more of a difference here.

Comment: I intend to upload the file to the database only once, and then edit the resulting table manually as I need to. The processing might be the biggest problem anyway, since I would explode() every array value/string into another array. Probably that's what should worry me the most I guess.